# how do I find full class name of an element?

Tags: html, css, class, styles, stylesheet

I am working with this css file and I can;t figure out what is the full class name of the button with noHover variant. I need it to be used in a different stylesheet. I cannot look it up in console as the classes are generated dynamically there. if it helps, the stylesheet name is: Button.module.scss. Any hints appreciated.`

```css
.main {
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 10px 30px;

  &:not(.noHover):hover {
    color: #ffffff !important;
    background-color: $primary;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

.small {
  @extend .main;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  
 
}


.outline {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #2a2a2a;
  color: #2a2a2a;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 22px;

  &:not(.noHover):hover {
    background-color: #2a2a2a;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
}
```

`

Comment: I dont't get your answer proper. but scss ist not css. it's sass file.
.noHover is a class name it's self.

Comment: If you want to find if there are another classes within this file, you can search it on inspector of your web browser.

Comment: Maybe this article will be helpful: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/developing-with-sass-and-chrome-devtools--net-32805

Comment: @hamid scss, of course. .noHover is a part of a class name, I need what goes first...What I see in console are only dynamic classes generated by JS I cannot use them. I hope I explained it well, English is not my first language.

Comment: ok, so I can see now you are right .noHiver is a full class. How can I use it in another stylesheet? I made @import "path" and it doesn't work

Comment: Do you work with a CMS (Like Wordpress) or just html and css?

Comment: scss and JS/react

Comment: First, if your Elements have classes (it dosn't matter if JS generates them), you can target them in your Stylesheet file.
Second, If your Elements have no classes, why don't you just add new classes to the Elements using HTML file?